# Getting JSON Tag Value into a text field in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, curl, json.net

I need to get the "uxfauthorization" tag value into a text box in ASP.NET. I am using curl to send the json request to server and getting below response from the server. I want "uxfauthorization" key value to be in text box so that user can view the authorization key.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Date: Tue, 08 Dec 2015 15:16:45 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 22
Content-Type: application/json
Expires: -1
SET-COOKIE:WIRELESS_SECURITY_TOKEN=HvsvzzAyux0oXBENeLPwtQ**___currentencryptionkey___36wByp   bpGkrOz/CQ6pTbGt44O+PpWvB0gu8hr12vIYa32j2Qg3Na3eylq5h4dZLeAmA6T6kZ4hevGJUjqXeFN8 2DIyEdaO7MVEqiemiGB90F7J0KXfiUdRjw5E5XkV9a; path=/; HttpOnly; 
uxf_lastLoginDate: 1449587736928
uxfauthorization:UXF_CSRFToken:csrfcurrentencryptionkey___dpU+veeOOvcV/0mrZKt3V8c4tI677cvo0hodpmXppOQ= UXF_SessionToken:HvsvzzAyux0oXBENeLPwtQ==___currentencryptionkey___36wBypbpGkrOz/CQ6pTbGt44O+PpWvB0gu8hr12vIYa32j2Qg3Na3eylq5h4dZLeAmA6T6kZ4hevGJUjqXeFN82DIyEdaO7MVEqiemiGB90F7J0KXfiUdRjw5E5XkV9a
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2

{"__EmptyObject__":{}}
```

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regular expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972966.aspx) to parse the value from the text. It can be something like below:

```
String pattern = @"uxfauthorization:(.*?)";
Regex re = new Regex(pattern);
MatchCollection matches = re.Matches(your_curl_response_here);
foreach(Match match in matches){
    // use the match.ToString() for your need
}
```

Comment: Hi Sabuj, I am very new to this. Can you please paste the exact code to achieve this? Thanks in advance for help :)